# Linux kernel: can't build module with non-retpoline compiler

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, compilation, spectre

OS - RedHat 8.5, kernel 4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64, gcc-8.5.0

I have installed `kernel-devel` and `kernel-headers`, and tried to build a very simple kernel module (just a pair of printk()).

Makefile:

```
obj-m += test_mod.o
MSRC ?= $(PWD)
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/
all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(MSRC) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(MSRC) clean
```

However I'm getting error:

```
%  make V=1
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64'
arch/x86/Makefile:249: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
%
```

Do I have to upgrade to a new compiler, if so which compiler version is needed? `man gcc` on my machine (RHEL8.5) says that `-mindirect-branch=` option is supported, and I believe this is the one enabling retpoline.

Should it be possible to disable `retpoline` support in the kernel? (however I would not like to rebuild the kernel if possible).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I disabled `retpoline` as suggested by *0andriy* via `grub` configuration file, (`cat /proc/cmdline` shows spectre_v2=off):

```
% grub2-editenv - set kernelopts=root=/dev/mapper/rhel_ps3cat5505k1-root ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/rhel_ps3cat5505k1-swap rd.lvm.lv=rhel_ps3cat5505k1/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel_ps3cat5505k1/swap rhgb quiet spectre_v2=off
% reboot
```

However the build still fails:

```
% make V=1
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ M=/home/mrv/tmp modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/mrv/tmp/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/mrv/tmp/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/mrv/tmp
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//home/mrv/tmp/test_mod.ko;) > /home/mrv/tmp/modules.order
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/mrv/tmp/.test_mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated   -I./include/drm-backport -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -DCONFIG_TPAUSE=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-int-in-bool-context -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -g -gdwarf-4 -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -fno-inline-functions-called-once -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -Wno-packed-not-aligned  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"test_mod"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"test_mod"' -c -o /home/mrv/tmp/.tmp_test_mod.o /home/mrv/tmp/test_mod.c
In file included from ./include/linux/module.h:18,
                 from /home/mrv/tmp/test_mod.c:1:
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:22:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘static’
 static const char __UNIQUE_ID(name)[]       \
 ^~~~~~
./include/linux/module.h:158:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘__MODULE_INFO’
 #define MODULE_INFO(tag, info) __MODULE_INFO(tag, tag, info)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/module.h:196:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_INFO’
 #define MODULE_LICENSE(_license) MODULE_INFO(license, _license)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mrv/tmp/test_mod.c:19:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_LICENSE’
 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:322: /home/mrv/tmp/test_mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1571: _module_/home/mrv/tmp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
%
```

So, running 'make oldconfig && make prepare' in kernel sources directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64` results in failure to locate `tools/build/Build.include`.

Not sure if RedHat allows to build kernel modules in RHEL8 at all.

**EDIT2**

Simple kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static __init int test_init(void)
{
   printk("Init module\n");
   return 0;
}

static __exit void test_exit(void)
{
   printk("Cleanup module\n");
}

module_init(test_init)
module_exit(test_exit)

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493398/how-to-disable-retpoline

Comment: Your error message and description are not aligned. Are you sure you understand the error? RHEL has specific packages to allow to build the 3rd party modules. No need to have full sources for that.

Comment: @0andriy, thanks for your feedback. There was indeed a bug in my simple kernel module! I forgot to add `;` at the end of `MODULE_*()` macros.